# Change image in image view ANDROID

Tags: android

i am creating a app as a part of assignment . It is turn bulb on or off when it is touhed.i am new and have no idea on how to do it.i just add one image in which bulb is off to the image viewer and now i donot know what to write in .java file to make it work..........

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:contentDescription="@string/off"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/off" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You should learn to work with the documentation, there are multiple `setImageXxx()` methods in the [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) class, which help you to set the image from any source. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

This small snippet does what you want:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private boolean isBulbOn = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.BulbImageView);
        iv.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.BulbImageView);

        isBulbOn = !isBulbOn;

        iv.setImageResource(isBulbOn ? R.drawable.bulb_on : R.drawable.bulb_off);
    }
}
```